# Fatal Error in PHP with PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error, class-constants

With a PHP web application, I'm encountering a fatal error with PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, but only on very rare hosting plans. It's saying this constant is not available. How do I detect that it's not available and not use it?

I mean, I can use the if (!defined(...)) if/then check, but will this still get the fatal error on those systems where MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE is not compiled with PDO? Note that there's a known bug regarding MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE and mysqlnd, where it's not compiled in cases where mysqlnd is installed. The bug is marked as "won't fix".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) properly, is my guess. You need to provide it a string.

```
if( defined( 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE' ) ) // note the quotes
{
    // do something useful with PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE
}
```

The above example doesn't issue any notice/warning/error in my setup (PHP 5.3.20, in which `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` is not defined), using `error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT )`.